# event that captures an inputField value

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, visualforce

Is there a way to capture the event on an inputField when the user selects a value from the browser dropdown list?

For example, the VF page has an inputField that is a lookup field.  The user could have typed in several values that they are looking for.  These values are cached by the browser and the user can click on the inputField and then select one of the previous values that they have typed and searched for.  Is there a way to capture that event in javascript?

I've tried onchange, onclick, onmouseout, onmouseup, and nothing seems to work. Once I select a value from the dropdown, I have to then either select out of the inputField for my javascript function to fire.  I need to capture the event when a user selects one of the cached values that is displayed as a dropdown list on the inputField.

Is there any way to handle and capture that event?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1. Can you please post relevant code ?
2. Have you tried apex:actionSupport tag ?

Comment: There is quite a bit of code.  I'll edit my original post to include both the controller and VF page.  I haven't tried the actionSupport tag.  I'm using the actionFunction tag.  I'm displaying all transactions for a specific contact.  Then I have filtering options to further limit the resultset.  The issue is around filtering for a lookup up field that points a Fund__c record.  I can't quite get that to work exactly how I  want.  It is behaving a little funky.  It kind of works, but not elegantly.

Comment: To help further clarify, here are a few of the issues around the filtering for Fund. First, I need to pass the value of the fund lookup to the controller and the actionFunction doesn't fire if a user just types in the Fund Name and clicks "Filter Results" or if they select one of the cached values and click "Filter Results".  That is the first issue.  Secondly, if a user filters on a fund that doesn't exist in the resultset, the lookup field automatically clears itself and doesn't provide any indication of what happened.  That is a poor user experience.

Comment: I will go over the code tomorrow but without looking at it i would suggest: Try and use actionSupport.